# Insert array during mongo insert

Tags: mongodb

How to perform below operation? Is is possible with insert operation (not asking for update)?

```
var items = db.items.find({});
var bulkShopInsert = db.shop.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulkShopInsert.insert({
 'shopName' : 'My shop',
 'items' : items <- here is what I would like to achieve
});
```

Comment: `items` is a "cursor" and not an array. Use `.toArray()`. `var items = db.items.find({}).toArray()`

Comment: There is subtale detail that is different in my actual code - the insert is a bulk insert. I receive Error: can't save a DBQuery object :
DBCollection.prototype._validateObject@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:227:15
DBCollection.prototype._validateForStorage@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:241:5
DBCollection.prototype._validateForStorage@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:252:13
Bulk/this.insert@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:663:17

Comment: @Neil Lunn that was the reason, easy one - thank you.